# Vector of vectors in contiguous memory

Tags: c++, coordinate-system

I have a class `Vector3d` with 3 double components and want to store several of them in a `Field`. For reasons of efficiency when sending a `Field` over a network via MPI, I would like to allocate contiguous memory in the `Field` class and let the `Vector3d`s store their components in that chunk of memory. In addition, `Vector3d`s should also be able to live without a `Field`; in this case, they have to care about their own memory allocation.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Field;

class Vector3d
{
    friend class Field;

    public:
        Vector3d() : components_(new double[3]) {}
        ~Vector3d() { delete[] components_; }
        Vector3d(const Vector3d &v) : components_(new double[3])
        {
            components_[0] = v.components_[0]; 
            components_[1] = v.components_[1]; 
            components_[2] = v.components_[2];
        }
        double & operator()(const std::size_t index) { return components_[index]; }

    private:
        Vector3d(double *ptr) : components_(ptr) {};
        double *components_;
};

class Field
{
    public:    
        Field(std::size_t size);
        ~Field();
        Vector3d & operator()(const std::size_t index) { return *(vectors_[index]); }

    private:
        std::vector<double> components_;
        std::vector<Vector3d *> vectors_;
};

Field::Field(std::size_t size) : components_(std::vector<double>(3 * size)), vectors_(std::vector<Vector3d *>(size, new Vector3d(0)))
{
    double *ptr = &components_[0];
    for (auto it = vectors_.begin(); it != vectors_.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->components_ = ptr;
        ptr += 3;
    }
} 

Field::~Field()
{
    for (auto it = vectors_.begin(); it != vectors_.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->components_ = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Field field(2);
    Vector3d &v = field(1);
    v(2) = 5;

    Vector3d v2 = v;
    v2(2) = 2;

    std::cout << field(1)(2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to hear what you think about this piece of code. Can this be considered a good solution or what would you change?

Comment: Lets say you have a 2d vector `std::vector<std::vector<double>> data` which is basically what you have.  If you wanted flatten it out you could use `for( auto& e : data) flat_vector.insert(flat_vector.end(), e.begin(), e.end())`

Comment: Why not distinguish between `vector3d_view` and `vector3d`, where a `_view` is non-owning?  As a bonus, a `vector3d` could store a `double data[3];`, and a `std::vector<vector3d>` would be contiguous memory already all by itself.  Making your primitive types "not care about ownership" is a recipe for inefficiency and bugs in my experience.  While casting a `std::vector<vector3d>` to a raw array of `double` is not permitted by the standard, it may work on your particular platform if `vector3d` contains nothing but the `double data[3];` (is standard layout)

Comment: @DrewDormann: Ok, my example might be a bit too long but I just wanted to make myself clear. To boil it down: What I need is a vector of vectors but stored in contiguous memory. Since this is not possible using `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, I thought illustrating my alternative with a piece of code would help people to understand my question better.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thanks for that suggestion but I think your solution involves a copy operation each time I want to access the aggregate vector. Since I have to do this very often in my application, I don't think this would be the right way to go.

Comment: @Yakk: I also came up with that solution but then I would have to treat `Vector3d_view` and `Vector3d` differently which is not what I want. Inheriting from a common base class also seems to be a bit overkill. Your suggestion for casting `std::vector<Vector3d>` to a raw array of `double` is not an option because I'm planning to add some functionality to the `Vector3d` class which would destroy contiguous memory layout.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to multidimensional vectors I usually suggest two approaches.

### 1. vector/array (C++11 and later)

This only works, when the inner dimensions are fixed and only the outer is runtime dynamic. In the end it comes down to something like this:

```
std::vector<std::array<T, N>> field;
```

In your case a Vector3d would either derive from std::array<double, 3> or contain one.

### 2. simple vector

This approach simply creates a one dimensional vector with `X * Y` size.
The element `(x, y)` can then be addressed with `vec[y * X + x]`. This works also with the older C++ standard. Although I think this solution might not work in your setup.

#### Bonus

I just want to highlight @Yakk's comment. Your Vector3d could look like this:

```
class Vector3d
{
public:
    // stuff
    // ...
private:
    double components_[3];
};
```

This way the memory would also be contigous.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Regarding your first solution, you suggest that the `Field` class holds a `std::vector<Vector3d>`, which, due to the fact that the `Vector3d` only holds `double components_[3]` as a sole member could be casted to a raw double array? Can this really considered to be good style? If sometime I decide to add members this solution won't work anymore... Actually, your second solution is what I had already but it would be better to access the individual entities of a field individually. What about my proposed solution? Do you see any memory issues?

Comment: I had to say something more after inspecting your code, so I commented it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/OsXh1l). Also [here](http://ideone.com/o740je) is a version that I would call "clean", though that does not have to mean much.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The idea was to create a `Vector3d` class which can also live on its own (and might have members in addition to `components_`). I know that `new double[3]` creates memory somewhere on the heap and that is what the default behavior should be. I don't see the memory leak (point me to it if I'm wrong!) because the `Field` class cares for memory allocation and deallocation. The `Field` class needs to store `std::vector<Vector3d *>` because I don't want the `Vector3d`'s copy constructor to be invoked (which would allocate memory a second time).

Comment: In the initializer list of the `Field` constructor, the private constructor of `Vector3d` is called with a `0` pointer (only used by the `Field` class!). In the loop, the pointer is assigned a new location.

Further, I don't see any issues using `operator()` instead of `operator[]`, I think this is just personal taste. The same for `const std::size_t`, instead of `std::size_t` - it doesn't harm. I was just following the rule "put `const` wherever you can". I didn't implement the `const` version of the access operators because I didn't want to make the examples longer than necessary.

Comment: Regarding your solution, you essentially use a `typedef` to `std::array<double, 3>`, i.e., the a vector does not have any operators or the like. Of course, you could embed it in a class and let it have just a single member (its components) but as soon as you add just one other member, memory contiguity would be destroyed. I would be happy if you could elaborate this issue.

Comment: It seems I was a bit tired yesterday... You are right, there is indeed no leak. Still messing around with another classes guts is usually not considered best practice. Also I already wrote in the code comments, that `operator()` is not an issue. Other than that I wonder why you would care if there were some extra bytes between each of the component triplets? The memory is still contiguous in the end. So some explanation would be nice, where you see problems with the straight forward solutions. [Look at this please.](http://ideone.com/Rxvd7W)

Comment: I also want to point out another issue that I noticed: http://ideone.com/BRLsXL

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I must admit that I have overseen that the entries in `vectors_` all point to the same `Vector3d` object. The reason why I need contiguous memory is that I need to pass the pointer to the first element of the raw array to an MPI function which then sends the complete array over the network. Sending each `Vector3d` is separately is extremely inefficient - that's why I want to avoid it.

Comment: Well that makes sense. As there is no real memory leak issue there, the only thing you got to fix is that all vectors_ elements point to the same thing. Although I would still try to get rid of that friend hack. Adding a `bool external` and making the pointer constructor `public` and `explicit` could be of help here. Also your vectors_ vector should maybe just be a `std::vector<Vector3d>` filled with `std::fill`. **EDIT** I see you already fixed that issue.